# EXC BAD ACCESS After Coding Signing

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

My App is using a custom C++ library and it was working perfectly fine before I enable **Automatically manage signing**, however, when I enable it I will get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=50, address=0x1011ff000)` (see screenshot).

Why this is happening and how to debug it?

[image]

I tried to use the debug guide [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544) to find the **Zombie Object** but nothing shows up.

**UPDATE** the issue was caused by invalid code sign in a framework I used in the app. The solution can be found at [How to fix dylib with invalid signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494279/how-to-fix-dylib-with-invalid-signature)

Comment: Is this app multithreaded?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 yes, the C++ lib is multithreaded.