# How to fix dylib with invalid signature?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, code-signing

Yesterday I was having an issue to run my app after auto code signing. See the question I post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484401/exc-bad-access-after-coding-signing) yesterday.

After spending some time to investigate the issue it turns out the framework certificate somehow corrupted.

The solution is to fix the invalid signature for the framework, and here is how to do so.

P.S. One thing we are certain is that we did tick the **Sign On Copy** checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: **VideoBuilderLibrary** is a custom framework we built.

To test the **code sign** state,

```
# Replace the framework to yours
codesign -v 
frameworks/VideoBuilderLibrary.framework/Frameworks/libavutil.55.dylib
[no output]
```

If there is any invalid signature,

```
codesign -v 
frameworks/VideoBuilderLibrary.framework/Frameworks/libavutil.55.dylib
frameworks/VideoBuilderLibrary.framework/Frameworks/libavutil.55.dylib: 
invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)
In architecture: x86_64
```

To resigned all `dylib` files in a framewor and fix this, run command below with "YOUR CERTIFICATE NAME" replaced with your cert file name,

```
cd frameworks/VideoBuilderLibrary.framework/Frameworks
ls | xargs codesign -f -s "YOUR CERTIFICATE NAME"
```