# XCODE Simulator Error After Update to 12.2 Exc_Bad_Access(code=50, address=0x11b40e1ad)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12

I update my system to Xcode 12.2, and sense doing so, I got an error on launching the simulator:[image]

If I use my iPhone with the same project, it works fine. Only the simulator crashes. If I make a new project, the simulators work in the new projects.

Not sure what to do as I'm not getting anything in the output either.
Anyone has seen this and knows how to fix it?

Things I have tried sense original Post:

Uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled.
Deleted Derived Folder
Deleted Ios Simulator folder.
Reinstalled Cocoapods.
Updated pods.

Comment: can you try delete the derived data ?

Comment: Possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48484401/14351818

Comment: I did delete the  derived folder, will check that link

Comment: @JustinSinnard Have you inserted any third party library without Cocoapods or spm?

Comment: @Rob I do have pods, KeychainSwift and Alamofire. but they were with Cocoapods, I did try to reinstall cocoapods with gem install, and updated my pods today.

Comment: Try downgrading or upgrading Xcode and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @Rob Alright just uninstalled and installed Xcode 12.0.1, still does the same thing when I try to run the simulator.

Comment: You have not shown us _any_ code. It's impossible to help without knowing _what_ is crashing.

Comment: @JustinSinnard Then start debugging from start, go to first app life cycle method add breakpoint, if it clears out test second one, if there is nothing wrong with Xcode, then it's your code which is wrong somewhere and then, you can add that code here in case you need help.

Comment: exc bad access code is error result of accessing bad memory, it hard for debugging.
You should use address sanitizer in diagnostic, it can help you to see what is happening. There is a memory issue somewhere in your code and simulator can't handle that, real device will crash after sometime too.

Comment: I guess I don't know where else to put a breakpoint. I put a breakpoint at viewDidLoad() on my first view controller. But it crashes before it ever reaches that breakpoint. So was assuming if it hasn't reached my code, it has to be something else.

Comment: Alright, I enabled address sanitizer, but from what I can see I still get no output and it crashes in dyl`_dyld_start:

Comment: Alright, so it looks like if I disable hardened Runtime in the targets build settings. It will allow the simulator to run fine. But not sure if that is a bad thing or a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem with this is that Hardened runtime needs to be disabled on your target:

select target-> Build settings -> Under Signing - Enable Hardened Runtime, select no.

It looks like this feature will break simulators, but not actual hardware.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to integrate all my 3rd party libraries as **xcframework** into my app structure. If the xcframework slices are created correctly, they contain the required code for running your app on simulators.

For those libraries that I didnt have access to their source code, I asked the owner to provide the xcframework version of their libraries.

ps. In my project Enable Hardened Runtime was already equal to NO and that couldnt be the problem.